# CentOS does not recognize compiled boost library

Tags: centos, boost

I have built and installed boost using the following steps:

```
# Boostrap and install
JOBS=`grep -c ^processor /proc/cpuinfo`
wget https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.67.0/source/boost_1_67_0.tar.bz2
tar xf boost_1_67_0.tar.bz2
cd boost_1_63_0
./bootstrap.sh
./b2 -d1 -j${JOBS} --with-thread --with-filesystem --with-python --with-regex -sHAVE_ICU=1 --with-program_options --with-system link=shared release toolset=gcc stage
./b2 -d1 -j${JOBS} --with-thread --with-filesystem --with-python --with-regex -sHAVE_ICU=1 --with-program_options --with-system link=shared release toolset=gcc install
sudo bash -c "echo '/usr/local/lib' > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/boost.conf"
sudo ldconfig
```

Then, I try to build mapnik which uses boost. I checkout [mapnik](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik) and run `./bootstrap.sh` and `./configure`. I get the error "Could not find required header or shared library for boost filesystem". The boost section of configure is as follows:

```
Searching for boost libs and headers... (cached) 
Found boost libs: mason_packages/.link/lib
Found boost headers: mason_packages/.link/include
Checking for C++ header file boost/version.hpp... yes
Checking for Boost version >= 1.61... yes
Found boost lib version... 
Checking for C++ library boost_system... no
Could not find required header or shared library for boost system
Checking for C++ library boost_filesystem... no
Could not find required header or shared library for boost filesystem
Checking for C++ library boost_regex... yes
Checking for C++ library boost_program_options... yes
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '':
  File "/root/src/mapnik/SConstruct", line 1600:
    boost_version = [int(x) for x in env.get('BOOST_LIB_VERSION_FROM_HEADER').split('_')]
```

(Build steps courtesy of  [keisan](https://www.keisan.io/knowledgebase/centos-7-open-street-map-tile-server))

Why doesn't the system find the boost library 1.67? I don't remember installing boost 1.63. I have compiled and installed 1.67, but the build system does not use it. Where does the system look for boost on the system? I deleted all libboost_* files in /usr/local/lib and /usr/lib64, but still don't know where the system looks for boost. Can someone give a tip on how to tell the system about the newly compiled software?

Answer (score 0):

Cent OS 7 user here, also trying to get Mapnik to build with optional dependencies, however mine does (seem to) recognize my updated Boost build. You've probably already surpassed this problem, side-stepped it, or forgotten about it, but I mention this anyway in case it might help you or someone else.

From what I am reading, it's almost like Mapnik wants/needs dependencies to be built using the same compiler in order to recognize those dependencies during the make/install steps. However, if you use this approach, it actually creates an alternative, non-default compiler, which you have to specify in your shell session in order to use in place of the default compiler.

I used this approach to update my compiler, build Boost, then configure Mapnik. So it might work for you.

> **Important**. Note specifically the `export CC=` and `export CXX=` instructions appearing in the second step. As this is where you override your default compiler, and it seems that most/all of the dependencies need to be built with this compiler.

First, get an updated gcc/g++ compiler from the gcc6 series with c++14 support:

```
## Instructions modified from here, I just changed the gcc version.. 
## https://linuxhostsupport.com/blog/how-to-install-gcc-on-centos-7/
## 
cd /root/downloads
screen -U -S gcc
wget http://ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/sourceware.org/pub/gcc/releases/gcc-6.5.0/gcc-6.5.0.tar.gz
tar zxf gcc-6.5.0.tar.gz
cd gcc-6.5.0
## Install bzip2 if you don't have it yet..
yum install bzip2
## Install gcc prereqs..
./contrib/download_prerequisites
./configure --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++
make -j 4
make install
```

Next, build and install Boost from source. This approach may result in a second installation of Boost. But you need to know where it lands in order to specify it during Mapnik's config step:

```
## Create temporary links to the new gcc/g++ compiler resources.
## These disappear with your shell session but need to be in effect for both the Boost and Mapnik builds.
## 
export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc
export CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++

cd /root/downloads
wget https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.69.0/source/boost_1_69_0.tar.gz
tar -xzf boost_1_*
cd boost_1_*
## This prefix variable sets the install location for boost, knowing this location is important. 
## This was the location suggested by the instructions I followed, which I've lost, but this seems to be a standard alternative location.
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/opt/boost
./b2 install --prefix=/opt/boost --with=all
```

Now Boost is installed and lives here: `/opt/boost/`

At this point, when building and installing Mapnik, you can specify your updated Boost version in the configure step, like below.

***This is important—*** If you have rebooted, or if you have logged out and logged back in, you need to repeat the `export CC=` and `export CXX=` instructions that appear at the top of the second step in order to ensure Mapnik builds with the same compiler you used to build Boost!

`./configure BOOST_LIBS=/opt/boost/lib BOOST_INCLUDES=/opt/boost/includes`

Hopefully this helps someone!